# How to make relative layout in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

Please see this image -https://ibb.co/YpjJsLZ

In above image how can I place burger image to center of white view.
I tried using `Align` & `Center` widget but its no fitting properly.

How can relative layout works in flutter?

Comment: Please push some code

Comment: You can easily achieve this using stack widget https://github.com/lohanidamodar/flutter_ui_challenges/blob/master/lib/src/pages/profile/profile2.dart , https://github.com/lohanidamodar/flutter_ui_challenges/blob/master/screenshots/profile2.png

Answer (score 0):

Flutter does not have layout types like android,

But you can place burger image using stack widget.

You can follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1VLr5NqUSTE) tutorial for reference.

Answer (score 0):

you can not use Relative Layout in Flutter but it Replace using "Stack".

The stack is a widget in Flutter that contains a list of widgets and positions them on top of the other.

stack allows developers to overlap multiple widgets into a single screen and renders them from bottom to top.

Hence, the first widget is the bottommost item, and the last widget is the topmost item.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StackWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StackWidgetState createState() => _StackWidgetState();
}

class _StackWidgetState extends State<StackWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.yellow,
      height: 300,
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.cyan,
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            width: 150,
            height: 150,
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]